# windows 7 networking lost router needs rebooting every 10 minutes

Tags: windows-7, networking

So this seems like a router problem, but it started happening since I installed Windows 7.

I often lose the network (networking icon gets exclamation mark) and need to reboot my router which fixes the problem temporarily.

I am using the Cisco Linksys router WRT160N V3.

Running Windows 7 Ultimate N 64 bit.

Also, rebooting solves the problem, so it's probably not a router issue.

The computer is connected to the router via cable.

Comment: Wired or wireless?

Comment: An additional note: If you're doing torrents or something to that effect that generates a ton of connections, I have seen linksys routers puke on that.  There are a couple of steps to take that can help if this is the case.

Comment: Do you only use a wired connection or do you have a wireless adapter enabled (although not in use) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it happened at the exact time of installing Windows 7, it most likely is down to a driver problem (please try updating your network drivers).

Do any other computers loose connections? IF the answer is no, it is obviously just your machine - another solution may be to try and disconnect and reconnect the network cable.

If driver doesn't help, I would recommend trying to disable Home Group and IPv6 on your machine as I have seen his causing a few problems in the past with older routers.

Comment: update - just read, your router is not that old at all, but I would still recommend the steps I wrote.

Comment: homegroup disabled. which drivers should i update, for my NIC ?

Comment: yes, pretty sure the NIC driver is what he's suggesting